# How to access blue iPhone contacts icon

Tags: iphone, google-maps, maps, contacts, addressbook

Does anyone know how to make use of the little contacts icon that appears at the right side of the search bar in the Google Maps application? I mean the little blue one which you tap when you want to select a contact from your Address Book.

I'm making an app which allows the user to enter a name into a Text Field, and I'd like to be able to provide that icon in the text field so the user will recognise it and know that it can be tapped to select a name directly from contacts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not provided by iOS, and I don't remember seeing it listed anywhere among the standard icons, then you're out of luck. You'll need to provide your own version while taking care not to step on anybody's IP.